# Are there any alternatives to Ionic View for iOS?

Tags: ios, ionic3, ionic-view

I continually have connection issues when attempting to preview iOS apps with Ionic 3.

No problems whatsoever with the Android side.

But iOS is just so temperamental and frustrating!

Connection errors, not Synching to latest etc?

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of luck sharing my app with Hockey App. You do need an apple developer account to use it with IOS though. And there are a few more steps involved than simply using uploading to Ionic Dashboard.

https://www.hockeyapp.net/

And the instructions to do this process is 
https://gist.github.com/SWTPAIN/a6f8bda444da4e3a5886

And if you are just testing on your own phone, it is much easier to just plug it in and run ionic cordova run --prod ios

Comment: Thanks. I want to make it easy to share changes with people who are beta testers and gather feedback..